# How should I generate a unique link per booking so my users can see a standalone email?

Tags: security, email, language-agnostic, hash

An email confirmation gets sent when my website users making a booking. I have been requested to add a "Having trouble viewing this email?" link to the top which links to the email on the website.

I'm having trouble wondering how I should generate a link so the user could view this email.

Note that I am using a third party booking system which gives me a confirmation code such as: `12345BE913913` where `12345` is the property and `BE` is always `BE` and `913913` is a secondary number. 
I'm wondering if I could just hash this number and make that the link? Eg `sha1('12345BE913913')` which turns into `070bae598f481351e24975d6509fc0a73cad9a17`

And then the link in the email becomes something like `href="http://blah.com/email/view/070bae598f481351e24975d6509fc0a73cad9a17`

**Question #1:** Is this a pretty standard, secure way of doing it?

If so, I have one other concern... I would need to pull in this information in order to generate the email in my `email/view`. The web service only accepts the confirmation code, so I would have to feed the original one, `12345BE913913` to it. So I can't simply grab all the confirmation codes, sha1 them all and see which one equates to `070bae598f481351e24975d6509fc0a73cad9a17`.

**Question #2:** Is my only option to get the booking information through the webservice that accepts the original confirmation code, to create a local database storing all the confirmation codes, and then get all of them SHA1'd and see if it equates to `070bae598f481351e24975d6509fc0a73cad9a17` to pull it up? It's not safe to use the actual confirmation code in the email, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not pass both the confirmation number (as the primary key) and a MAC associated with it (to prevent people from guessing URLs.

URL Generation Pseudocode:

```
$mac = HMAC_SHA1($server_secret, $confCode);
$url = "http://$baseURL?conf=$confCode&m=$mac";
```

Email Display Pseudocode:

```
$mac = getParam("m");
$confCode = getParam("conf");
$expectedMac = HMAC_SHA1($server_secret, $confCode);
if($mac != $expectedMac) { # Or in real perl, ne instead of !=
  return errorPage();
}
return email($confCode);
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need a local database that maps confirmation codes with the $server/secret or MACs? Edit: Oh, you generate it based on the confirmation code?

Comment: A single secret is used for all of the MACs.  The link provides you with confirmation code and the MAC.  You don't need to store anything except for a single server secret.

Comment: Stupid question but how would you generate the server secret? Can it be a relatively simple phrase with numbers or would you recommend a long one?

Comment: Not a stupid question at all.  Since it is only going to be used by a computer (and never a human) it can (and should) be long and random.  I'd generate a 16 character random password with a good password generator and use that.

Answer (score 1):

Why use SHA1 if you need the operation to be reversible? Why not instead encrypt it using a symetric algorithm such as Twofish to generate the URL. You can decrypt it on the server side using your key to recover the original confirmation code, then send the confirmation code to the 3rd party booking system. Since nobody else has your key, nobody else can recover the confirmation code.

Comment: What about AES instead of Twofish? "Blowfish was the direct predecessor to Twofish. Twofish was Bruce Schneier's entry into the competition that produced AES. It was judged as inferior to an entry named Rijndael, which was what became AES."

Answer (score 1):

Hashing the real identifier, and storing the hash as the key in a table to the original value for "reverse lookup" is a conventional approach.

That isn't the only option, however. You could encrypt the confirmation code. Since the confirmation codes are short and, and (I'm presuming) unique, it would be alright to use ECB mode with a block cipher, which would keep the resulting cipher text short (16 bytes instead of SHA-1's 20 bytes).

The caveat with ECB is that the same confirmation code will always produce the same cipher text. Most likely, a code is only sent in a single email; but, if it is sent more than once, an attacker would be able to determine that the email relates to the same confirmation code (but they wouldn't be able to determine the confirmation code itself).

I'm not sure what you mean by "safe". What can someone do with the confirmation number? Would they be able to use the hash to get the confirmation number from your site? Unless you use S/MIME (or PGP), an email is not private; assume an attacker can read email.